# Jquery draggable only run in jquery min 1.5.0 and 1.7.1

Tags: jquery, drag, jquery-ui-draggable

I have this code, to run draggable elements with jQuery:

```
$('.drags').draggable( {
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: 'document',
    helper: function() {
    var isto = $(this).attr('id');
    return '<img src="design/imagens/'+isto+'.fw.png" width="52" height="48" />';
}});
```

to run this I need 2 jQuery plugins:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js

so jQuery version 1.7.1 is old no? I try to put jQuery version 1.9.8 but that's is new version, and when I put it, my code draggable doesn't run anymore..why?

Comment: are you sure `to run this i need 2 jquery plugins:` .. 2 jquery plugins!!! (i don't think so ) anyways if yes!! then you better avoid using such plugins.. start looking for other draggable plugins..

Answer (score 0):

Jquery UI 1.8.9 is very old, try the new version (v1.10.3):

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js